# Turning of gzip on nginx for some uris

Tags: nginx, proxy, gzip

I have this nodejs app behind nginx, let's call it A. Some requests to the app are proxied to another nginx/nodejs server (this is B, a backend API) by the nodejs app (not by nginx).

Currently, both nginx enable gzip compression, which is an issue. Responses from B to A are compressed, and A compresses them again, making the response unusable by the browser.

The ideal solution would be to tell A not to compress responses for requests transferred to B. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Here's my nginx config on A:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types application/json;

location / {

  if ($request ~ /api/) {
    gzip off;
  }
  # proxy to the node app
  proxy_redirect   off;
  proxy_pass       http://wtb-backoffice;
}
```

With that setup, proxied requests are still double-compressed. If I replace `gzip off` with `return 404`, surely my `/api/smth` requests return a 404, so the condition is right.

If I turn off compression on server B and enable it on A without the location condition to turn it off, the content is compressed once, and thus readable - which makes sense. But with the `gzip off` condition present, responses are received uncompressed.
So I conclude that the `gzip off` directive works only when the raw content is uncompressed. Otherwise it will stupidly compress it again. Does it make sense for someone, and how can I fix that?

BTW, before you suggest stopping proxying or using nginx for the proxy: A and B do not use the same authentication mechanisms, so the proxy controller on A does some magic and cannot be bypassed.